# Tkinter scrollbar strangeness

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a program to help me simplify putting notes into work tickets. I have been able to get the UI working just fine on one machine but on other machines it looks different. The only issue I have is with the scrollbars. I am using Tkinter for the UI framework as that is the only one that is whitelisted and all machines are running the same Windows 7 64-bit and Python environment.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.simpledialog

# create the window
top = Tk()
top.title("Notes Generator")
top.resizable(0, 0)
top.option_add("*Font", "Times 10")

txtDiscovery = Text(top, height=6, wrap=WORD)
scrolldiscovery = ttk.Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL, command=txtDiscovery.yview)
txtDiscovery['yscrollcommand'] = scrolldiscovery.set
txtDiscovery.grid(row=3, columnspan=4, rowspan=6, padx=(8, 0), pady=8)
scrolldiscovery.grid(row=3, column=4, rowspan=6, sticky='nsew', padx=(0, 8), pady=8)


# Loop the loop
top.mainloop()
```

[This is the way it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vew.png)

[This is the way it's actually looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YodD7.png)

EDIT: My apologies for not including all necessary information. The working frame of the program that still generates the layout anomaly has been included.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Layout problems can't usually be debugged in a vacuum. The solution is probably to add a weight to one or more of the columns 0-3, and/or to use the `sticky` attribute for the text widget so that it fills the space given to it.

Comment: Avoid importing tkinter twice. Remove the `from tkinter import *` line as its not needed.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to trim it down to something both minimal and complete. For example, you probably don't need any of the functions near the top, or to set the iconbitmap, or the bindings, and you really only need one text widget and scrollbar.

Comment: I took your suggestion Mike but unfortunately it broke large portions of my code. I am open to any suggestions given. I am still learning and also new to this site. If I am submitting something incorrectly I will gladly go back and fix it.

Comment: This code looks fine. The scrollbar is right up against the text widget. We need code that reproduces your problem, so we can use it as a basis to fix it. Start with your existing code. Remove something that seems unrelated. Still have the problem? Remove another chunk. Still have the problem? Remove another chunk. And so on. Keep removing chunks until the problem goes away, then replace the last chunk you removed. Try removing other chunks. Keep at it until you have the smallest code possible that still has the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue. In the full version of the code I had an extra frame at the bottom of the window containing several buttons. I had the width of these buttons set in the code and for some reason Python was assigning a different pixel value between my machine and other machines. This caused the frame at the bottom of the screen to be wider on other machines and made the last column wider to compensate. I was able to use the grid_columnconfigure to setup 3 equal columns for my buttons and expand them with the sticky option. I didn't know grid_columnconfigure existed or what it did.